# datalayerlistener not receiving messages on wearable (intent filter not working)

Tags: android, wear-os, intentfilter

I want to send a message to my wearable device. I debugged it to the intent filter in my manifest file, more specifically the data tag in the intent filter I think.

This is the wear manifest file

```
<service android:name="be.prizorgo.shaketosave.communication.DataLayerListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <!--<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />-->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="mobile" android:host="*"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This is where I suppose the problem is. So to be clear if I only use the deprecated bind_listener then it works as soon as I add the data tag it stops working and I don't know why. Is it because I don't use a path in the data tag because I read that it is optional.

So to be clear as soon as I add the data tag it stops working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<data android:scheme="mobile" android:host="*"/>`

With `<data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"/>`

Comment: thank you! that was a stupid mistake on my part. I was thinking this is the wearable so I need to say I receive messages from my mobile